# Redirecting whole directory to new directory within same domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I have a domain with Joomla installed. I didn't notice that Google cached so many obsolete URLs. I changed the old domain URL [in Joomla] to new one and all those cached links appeared into broken links. My old and new structure of URLs is:
Old:

```
www.domain.com/blog/01
www.domain.com/blog/02
www.domain.com/blog/03
www.domain.com/blog/04
www.domain.com/blog/05?start=5000
www.domain.com/blog/05?start=6000
www.domain.com/blog/05.html?start=7000
www.domain.com/blog/05.html?start=7000
```

.......... etc etc

So I want to redirect all those obsolete links from old address to `www.domain.com/blogs`
I prefer 301 permanently moved option.
How can I do that?
There is Joomla redirect function but I prefer .htaccess method because there are thousands of broken links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/ /blogs? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't work, by the way it was Joomla website. I want to redirect all old links from www.domain.com/blog/......sublinks inside it to www.domain.com/blogs

Comment: Check edited rule. Make sure this rule is your first rule in your htaccess.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was nearly to the end of the file before. It works just the way I wanted!